# accessing google docs by emails

Tags: google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

We can access public google docs and spreadsheets with ids or keys specified in the URL. But is it possible to access, download these with only email specified?

If we provide the email, can we fetch the docs and spreadsheets associated to this email?

Also, I would like to know is there anything in PHP which can do it?

Answer (score 0):

With the Google Drive API you can search for documents by owner, as in the following query:

```
'test@example.org' in owners
```

For more details, check the documentation at
https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters